# What does it mean to self-host GitLab?

Tags: 20.04, github, gitlab

[GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) is an open-source alternative to the Microsoft-owned GitHub, and I wanted to give it a try. I am not sure I understand what it means to [self-host GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/install/): Does it mean that my Ubuntu PC transforms into a Server that has to be on for 24 hours?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self-managed option gives you more control, but you need to deal with two things:

- Hosting either on your own server in your own network or on a dedicated / virtual server leased from hosting providers on the Internet.
- Installation and administration of the software itself.

The other option is (SaaS) which means **gitlab.com** takes care of the above for you.

More information [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GxO6qvATwU) and [here](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/marketing/strategic-marketing/dot-com-vs-self-managed/).

OS and hardware requirements are listed [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html).

Installation instructions are available [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/index.html).

**Notice:**

- A server does not need to run 24 hours, but the software / solutions on the server are only available when the server is up and running.
- A server does not mean necessarily that Ubuntu server edition OS must be used. You can use Ubuntu desktop edition on a machine and use it like a server.

So basically you can install the self-managed Gitlab on your PC and turn the PC off when you are not using it if that is what you are asking.

Comment: +1, very helpful! I would have a follow-up question concerning your Server if I install GitLab on my own PC, which I turn off at night: Does it mean that I will have to use Ubuntu Server? I myself have Ubuntu 18.04 installed..

Comment: @Anonymous5638 No, you do not have to use Ubuntu server. Ubuntu desktop edition is OK.

Comment: Accepted the answer, thanks. One follow-up, though: If I self-host it on my Linux machine, would that take away too many resources? I have 11.7 GB of RAM, an Intel i5 with 4 cores.

Comment: @Anonymous5638 For just one user... It should not need a lot of resources. The requirements are, however, listed [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html) scroll down that page for hardware requirements. You are most welcome.